# Android error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.MenuItem.getActionProvider

Tags: android, shareactionprovider

I enabled the `ShareActionProvider` and I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.MenuItem.getActionProvider
```

But the way I use this class is like this:

```
    // SHARING ONLY ENABLED in SDK 14 which is Ice Cream Sandwich
    try
    {           
        if ( android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14 )
        {
            Button share = (Button)findViewById(R.id.share_button); 
            share.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
            {  
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {                   
                    openOptionsMenu();
                }
            });        
        }
        else
        {
            // HIDE THE TWO PAGE ELEMENTS
            Button share = (Button)findViewById(R.id.share_button); 
            TextView share_prompt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.share_prompt); 

            share.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            share_prompt.setVisibility(View.GONE);              
        }
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {

    }
```

So I thought that I would not show the share button for earlier sdk's and I would be ok. But I am getting a lot of crashes.

I can not really test this because I don't have a phone with an earlier version of the SDK. But does it mean that these pages crash for everyone who has the earlier SDK version? Or just people who click share?  How do I prevent this crashing?

And I have these methods in the class. Should I just not run them if sdk is less than 14?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
    myShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider)item.getActionProvider();
    myShareActionProvider.setShareHistoryFileName(
      ShareActionProvider.DEFAULT_SHARE_HISTORY_FILE_NAME);
    myShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());
    return true;
}

private Intent createShareIntent() 
{
       Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
       shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
       shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, 
         "Some text");
       return shareIntent;
}

// Somewhere in the application.
public void doShare(Intent shareIntent) 
{
    // When you want to share set the share intent.
    myShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
}
```

Thanks.
Alex

Answer (score 4):

`ShareActionProvider` is available only for API 14+ which means in earlier versions you can't use it. If you want to add share button in your app and support old API levels I can suggest you to use [ActionBarSherlock](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock) - a library which gives you the opportunity to use ActionBar in older versions of Android. Using this library you can do something like this to add share button :

```
MenuItem actionItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share_action_provider_action_bar);
ShareActionProvider actionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) actionItem.getActionProvider();
actionProvider.setShareHistoryFileName(ShareActionProvider.DEFAULT_SHARE_HISTORY_FILE_NAME);
actionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());


private Intent createShareIntent() {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(getFileStreamPath("shared.png"));
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    return shareIntent;
}
```

Which will share an image file. If you don't want to support older API levels I would suggest you just check for API level and depending on that use `ShareActionProvider`.

Hope this help.

Comment: what about if I wrap the call in a try/catch?

Comment: if you are using actionbarsherlock, you don't need a try/catch block. just don't forget to include shareactionprovider from abs library, not android. that's all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to have those same checks for your menu items. See the docs for [`getActionProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#getActionProvider%28%29). It's only supported on 14+. To test this kind of thing without a device, you can try on an emulator that uses an older version of Android.

Answer (score 1):

In documentation you can see that [MenuItem.getActionProvifer()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#getActionProvider%28%29) from 14 API, of course you will catch `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` on older versions (that errors you will catch every time when use methods or classes from new API).

Using try-catch can't save you:) You need to use different implementations with workarounds hanler-classes for different critical API versions.

If you will use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/), you can use that method in Android API >= 8. Try to save functional for maximem API, it will be great!

Comment: Thanks. What if I also add a try/catch in the actual onCreateOptionsMenu method?

Comment: @Genadinik, NoSuchMethodError extends http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html and, as I know, you can't catch it with try-catch.

Answer (score 1):

A little late....

> ShareActionProvider and in general ActionProviders are added from Android 4.0 (API Level 14) to Android Framework.
>   But the AndroidSupportLibrary helps us to support this feature in previous versions as well. But generally we do a mistake importing the ShareActionProvider from the Android SDK framework but not the SupportLibrary.

- CODE:

-->In the main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_share" android:title="@string/menuitem_detail_share"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
</menu>
```

**Note**: Observe that the 'app' namespace is used and not 'android' namespace'
WHY? => This is necessary when using any XML attributes defined by the support library, because these attributes do not exist in the Android framework on older devices. So you must use your own namespace as a prefix for all attributes defined by the support library.

-->In the Activity's onCreateOptionsMenu() :

```
ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem);
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "The Text you want to share);
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
```

**Note**: ShareActionProvider is imported from "import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider" and observe the usage of "MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider()" to get the ActionProvider instance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add condition to your when you support lower APIs while still using higher API calls. IT will fail in such case as there's simply no such method yet. And I'd suggest to slightly improve readability for your code, by replacing lines like:

```
if ( android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14 )
```

with

```
if ( android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWITCH )
```